# React Mermaid 9.0.1 flowchart graph: syntax error in graph data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, flowchart, gojs, mermaid

This is my code for the Mermaid Flowchart Component

```
import React from "react";
import mermaid from "mermaid";

mermaid.initialize({
    startOnLoad: true
});

/**
* Component.
*/
class WorkflowGraph extends React.Component {
    
    /**
    * lifecycle method of component.
    */
    componentDidMount() {
        mermaid.contentLoaded();
    }
    /**
      * render method.
      * @return {string}
      */
    render() {
        return <div className="mermaid">{this.props.chart }</div>;
    }
}

const WorkflowFlowchart = (props) => {
    const { graphData } = props
    
        return (
        <div style={{display:"flex",justifyContent:"center"}}>
            <WorkflowGraph
                chart={graphData}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default WorkflowFlowchart
```

I am getting the graphData via api and passing it as a props. This is the graph data

API response

```
{
    "statusCode": 0,      
    "graphData": "`graph TB;112((112))--BRE_RESPONSE_AWAITED-->366((366));style 112 fill:#0f0,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;style 112 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;366((366))--BRE_SUCCESS-->355((355));style 366 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;366((366))--BRE_ERROR-->356((356));style 366 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;355((355))--MAQUETTE_FRAUD_CHECK_FAILURE-->179((179));style 355 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;355((355))--BANKING_ACTION_DONE-->428((428));style 355 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;355((355))--BANK_VALIDATION_PENDING-->558((558));style 355 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;558((558))--DOCUMENT_UPLOADED-->114((114));style 558 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))--EMANDATE_SUCCESS-->557((557));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;428((428))-->557((557));style 428 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;557((557))--LOAN_AGREEMENT_SUCCESS-->353((353));style 557 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;557((557))--APPLICATION_PENDING-->555((555));style 557 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;557((557))--LOAN_APPLICATION_ACCEPTED-->350((350));style 557 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;353((353))--QC_ACTION_PENDING-->181((181));style 353 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;353((353))--QC_ALLOCATION_REJECTED-->180((180));style 353 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;180((180))-->181((181));style 180 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;181((181))--PANEL_SUCCESS-->166((166));style 181 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;181((181))--LOAN_QC_REJECTED-->358((358));style 181 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;181((181))--QC_REJECTED-->183((183));style 181 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;183((183))-->114((114));style 183 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->181((181));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->180((180));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;347((347))--LMS_CALLBACK_SUCCESS-->330((330));style 347 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;166((166))-->350((350));style 166 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;166((166))--PREDISBURSAL_FAILED-->357((357));style 166 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;166((166))-->555((555));style 166 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;357((357))-->350((350));style 357 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;357((357))-->555((555));style 357 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;350((350))--KAFKA_PUSH_SUCCESS-->700((700));style 350 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;350((350))--KAFKA_PUSH_FAILED-->701((701));style 350 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;555((555))-->700((700));style 555 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;555((555))-->701((701));style 555 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;700((700))--LMS_SUBMIT_APPLICATION_SUCCESS-->346((346));style 700 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;701((701))-->346((346));style 701 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;700((700))--LMS_SUBMIT_APPLICATION_FAILED-->347((347));style 700 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;701((701))-->347((347));style 701 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;347((347))-->346((346));style 347 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;700((700))--LOAN_APPLICATION_REJECTED-->351((351));style 700 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;701((701))-->351((351));style 701 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;351((351))-->347((347));style 351 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;351((351))-->346((346));style 351 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;346((346))-->330((330));style 346 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;346((346))--LMS_CALLBACK_REJECTED-->333((333));style 346 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;346((346))--LMS_CALLBACK_PENDING-->334((334));style 346 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;346((346))--LMS_CALLBACK_FAILED-->345((345));style 346 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;330((330))--LEAD_SUCCESSFULLY_CLOSED-->156((156));style 330 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;333((333))--NOTIFICATION_SUCCESS-->167((167));style 333 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;333((333))--NOTIFICATION_ERROR-->168((168));style 333 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;167((167))--LEAD_FAILURE-->504((504));style 167 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;168((168))-->504((504));style 168 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;334((334))-->330((330));style 334 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;334((334))-->333((333));style 334 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;334((334))-->345((345));style 334 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;334((334))-->334((334));style 334 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;345((345))-->330((330));style 345 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;345((345))-->333((333));style 345 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;345((345))-->334((334));style 345 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;345((345))-->345((345));style 345 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;112((112))-->114((114));style 112 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;700((700))-->350((350));style 700 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;346((346))-->504((504));style 346 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;346((346))--LMS_CALLBACK_PENDING_BANK_PAN-->359((359));style 346 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;112((112))-->358((358));style 112 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->350((350));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->357((357));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->555((555));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;558((558))-->428((428));style 558 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;558((558))-->558((558));style 558 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;558((558))-->179((179));style 558 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;366((366))--UPDATE_LOAN_OFFER-->377((377));style 366 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;377((377))-->355((355));style 377 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;428((428))-->428((428));style 428 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->428((428));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;428((428))-->179((179));style 428 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->179((179));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;`",
}
```

```
`graph TB;112((112))--BRE_RESPONSE_AWAITED-->366((366));style 112 fill:#0f0,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;style 112 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;366((366))--BRE_SUCCESS-->355((355));style 366 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;366((366))--BRE_ERROR-->356((356));style 366 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;355((355))--MAQUETTE_FRAUD_CHECK_FAILURE-->179((179));style 355 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;355((355))--BANKING_ACTION_DONE-->428((428));style 355 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;355((355))--BANK_VALIDATION_PENDING-->558((558));style 355 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;558((558))--DOCUMENT_UPLOADED-->114((114));style 558 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))--EMANDATE_SUCCESS-->557((557));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;428((428))-->557((557));style 428 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;557((557))--LOAN_AGREEMENT_SUCCESS-->353((353));style 557 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;557((557))--APPLICATION_PENDING-->555((555));style 557 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;557((557))--LOAN_APPLICATION_ACCEPTED-->350((350));style 557 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;353((353))--QC_ACTION_PENDING-->181((181));style 353 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;353((353))--QC_ALLOCATION_REJECTED-->180((180));style 353 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;180((180))-->181((181));style 180 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;181((181))--PANEL_SUCCESS-->166((166));style 181 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;181((181))--LOAN_QC_REJECTED-->358((358));style 181 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;181((181))--QC_REJECTED-->183((183));style 181 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;183((183))-->114((114));style 183 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->181((181));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->180((180));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;347((347))--LMS_CALLBACK_SUCCESS-->330((330));style 347 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;166((166))-->350((350));style 166 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;166((166))--PREDISBURSAL_FAILED-->357((357));style 166 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;166((166))-->555((555));style 166 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;357((357))-->350((350));style 357 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;357((357))-->555((555));style 357 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;350((350))--KAFKA_PUSH_SUCCESS-->700((700));style 350 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;350((350))--KAFKA_PUSH_FAILED-->701((701));style 350 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;555((555))-->700((700));style 555 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;555((555))-->701((701));style 555 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;700((700))--LMS_SUBMIT_APPLICATION_SUCCESS-->346((346));style 700 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;701((701))-->346((346));style 701 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;700((700))--LMS_SUBMIT_APPLICATION_FAILED-->347((347));style 700 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;701((701))-->347((347));style 701 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;347((347))-->346((346));style 347 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;700((700))--LOAN_APPLICATION_REJECTED-->351((351));style 700 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;701((701))-->351((351));style 701 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;351((351))-->347((347));style 351 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;351((351))-->346((346));style 351 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;346((346))-->330((330));style 346 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;346((346))--LMS_CALLBACK_REJECTED-->333((333));style 346 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;346((346))--LMS_CALLBACK_PENDING-->334((334));style 346 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;346((346))--LMS_CALLBACK_FAILED-->345((345));style 346 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;330((330))--LEAD_SUCCESSFULLY_CLOSED-->156((156));style 330 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;333((333))--NOTIFICATION_SUCCESS-->167((167));style 333 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;333((333))--NOTIFICATION_ERROR-->168((168));style 333 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;167((167))--LEAD_FAILURE-->504((504));style 167 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;168((168))-->504((504));style 168 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;334((334))-->330((330));style 334 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;334((334))-->333((333));style 334 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;334((334))-->345((345));style 334 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;334((334))-->334((334));style 334 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;345((345))-->330((330));style 345 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;345((345))-->333((333));style 345 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;345((345))-->334((334));style 345 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;345((345))-->345((345));style 345 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;112((112))-->114((114));style 112 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;700((700))-->350((350));style 700 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;346((346))-->504((504));style 346 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;346((346))--LMS_CALLBACK_PENDING_BANK_PAN-->359((359));style 346 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;112((112))-->358((358));style 112 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->350((350));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->357((357));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->555((555));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;558((558))-->428((428));style 558 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;558((558))-->558((558));style 558 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;558((558))-->179((179));style 558 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;366((366))--UPDATE_LOAN_OFFER-->377((377));style 366 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;377((377))-->355((355));style 377 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;428((428))-->428((428));style 428 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->428((428));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;428((428))-->179((179));style 428 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->179((179));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;`
```

Even though the syntax is correct I am getting the syntax error in grap message.

if I hardcode the same in the code and it works fine.

```
 <WorkflowGraph
                chart={`graph TB;112((112))--BRE_RESPONSE_AWAITED-->366((366));style 112 fill:#0f0,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;style 112 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;366((366))--BRE_SUCCESS-->355((355));style 366 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;366((366))--BRE_ERROR-->356((356));style 366 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;355((355))--MAQUETTE_FRAUD_CHECK_FAILURE-->179((179));style 355 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;355((355))--BANKING_ACTION_DONE-->428((428));style 355 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;355((355))--BANK_VALIDATION_PENDING-->558((558));style 355 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;558((558))--DOCUMENT_UPLOADED-->114((114));style 558 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))--EMANDATE_SUCCESS-->557((557));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;428((428))-->557((557));style 428 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;557((557))--LOAN_AGREEMENT_SUCCESS-->353((353));style 557 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;557((557))--APPLICATION_PENDING-->555((555));style 557 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;557((557))--LOAN_APPLICATION_ACCEPTED-->350((350));style 557 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;353((353))--QC_ACTION_PENDING-->181((181));style 353 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;353((353))--QC_ALLOCATION_REJECTED-->180((180));style 353 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;180((180))-->181((181));style 180 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;181((181))--PANEL_SUCCESS-->166((166));style 181 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;181((181))--LOAN_QC_REJECTED-->358((358));style 181 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;181((181))--QC_REJECTED-->183((183));style 181 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;183((183))-->114((114));style 183 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->181((181));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->180((180));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;347((347))--LMS_CALLBACK_SUCCESS-->330((330));style 347 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;166((166))-->350((350));style 166 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;166((166))--PREDISBURSAL_FAILED-->357((357));style 166 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;166((166))-->555((555));style 166 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;357((357))-->350((350));style 357 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;357((357))-->555((555));style 357 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;350((350))--KAFKA_PUSH_SUCCESS-->700((700));style 350 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;350((350))--KAFKA_PUSH_FAILED-->701((701));style 350 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;555((555))-->700((700));style 555 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;555((555))-->701((701));style 555 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;700((700))--LMS_SUBMIT_APPLICATION_SUCCESS-->346((346));style 700 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;701((701))-->346((346));style 701 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;700((700))--LMS_SUBMIT_APPLICATION_FAILED-->347((347));style 700 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;701((701))-->347((347));style 701 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;347((347))-->346((346));style 347 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;700((700))--LOAN_APPLICATION_REJECTED-->351((351));style 700 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;701((701))-->351((351));style 701 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;351((351))-->347((347));style 351 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;351((351))-->346((346));style 351 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;346((346))-->330((330));style 346 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;346((346))--LMS_CALLBACK_REJECTED-->333((333));style 346 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;346((346))--LMS_CALLBACK_PENDING-->334((334));style 346 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;346((346))--LMS_CALLBACK_FAILED-->345((345));style 346 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;330((330))--LEAD_SUCCESSFULLY_CLOSED-->156((156));style 330 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;333((333))--NOTIFICATION_SUCCESS-->167((167));style 333 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;333((333))--NOTIFICATION_ERROR-->168((168));style 333 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;167((167))--LEAD_FAILURE-->504((504));style 167 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;168((168))-->504((504));style 168 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;334((334))-->330((330));style 334 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;334((334))-->333((333));style 334 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;334((334))-->345((345));style 334 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;334((334))-->334((334));style 334 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;345((345))-->330((330));style 345 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;345((345))-->333((333));style 345 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;345((345))-->334((334));style 345 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;345((345))-->345((345));style 345 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;112((112))-->114((114));style 112 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;700((700))-->350((350));style 700 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;346((346))-->504((504));style 346 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;346((346))--LMS_CALLBACK_PENDING_BANK_PAN-->359((359));style 346 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;112((112))-->358((358));style 112 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->350((350));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->357((357));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->555((555));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;558((558))-->428((428));style 558 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;558((558))-->558((558));style 558 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;558((558))-->179((179));style 558 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;366((366))--UPDATE_LOAN_OFFER-->377((377));style 366 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;377((377))-->355((355));style 377 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;428((428))-->428((428));style 428 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->428((428));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;428((428))-->179((179));style 428 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->179((179));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;`}
            />
```

Comment: How are you using `WorkflowFlowChart`?

Comment: rendering inside modal

Comment: You're gonna have to be more specific than that. Some code showcasing how you use the component would be nice.

Comment: I am opening component inside a modal         dispatch(openViewDefaultModal(<WorkflowFlowchart graphData={graphData}/>,"Workflow Flowchart", "default", "Close", undefined, "90vw", "component", undefined,undefined));

Comment: Okay, but then what is `graphData` and where do you get it from? Make sure to edit your question with the surrounding code of where you use it to help others trying to answer.

Comment: graphData is the data received from api.

Comment: I have mentioned it above

Comment: Please, would it kill for there to be more information than this? Help us help you! We need code where you send and receive the data. In any case, it's likely that the API is returning malformed data.

Comment: I have added the api response

Comment: See now that you've included all the important parts, I was able to post a suitable answer! Make sure to include all relevant parts in your future questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your API response includes backticks that surround the actual data:

```json
{
    "statusCode": 0,      
    "graphData": "`graph TB;112((112))--BRE_RESPONSE_AWAITED-->366((366));style 112 fill:#0f0,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;style 112 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;366((366))--BRE_SUCCESS-->355((355));style 366 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;366((366))--BRE_ERROR-->356((356));style 366 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;355((355))--MAQUETTE_FRAUD_CHECK_FAILURE-->179((179));style 355 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;355((355))--BANKING_ACTION_DONE-->428((428));style 355 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;355((355))--BANK_VALIDATION_PENDING-->558((558));style 355 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;558((558))--DOCUMENT_UPLOADED-->114((114));style 558 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))--EMANDATE_SUCCESS-->557((557));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;428((428))-->557((557));style 428 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;557((557))--LOAN_AGREEMENT_SUCCESS-->353((353));style 557 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;557((557))--APPLICATION_PENDING-->555((555));style 557 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;557((557))--LOAN_APPLICATION_ACCEPTED-->350((350));style 557 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;353((353))--QC_ACTION_PENDING-->181((181));style 353 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;353((353))--QC_ALLOCATION_REJECTED-->180((180));style 353 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;180((180))-->181((181));style 180 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;181((181))--PANEL_SUCCESS-->166((166));style 181 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;181((181))--LOAN_QC_REJECTED-->358((358));style 181 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;181((181))--QC_REJECTED-->183((183));style 181 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;183((183))-->114((114));style 183 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->181((181));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->180((180));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;347((347))--LMS_CALLBACK_SUCCESS-->330((330));style 347 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;166((166))-->350((350));style 166 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;166((166))--PREDISBURSAL_FAILED-->357((357));style 166 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;166((166))-->555((555));style 166 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;357((357))-->350((350));style 357 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;357((357))-->555((555));style 357 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;350((350))--KAFKA_PUSH_SUCCESS-->700((700));style 350 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;350((350))--KAFKA_PUSH_FAILED-->701((701));style 350 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;555((555))-->700((700));style 555 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;555((555))-->701((701));style 555 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;700((700))--LMS_SUBMIT_APPLICATION_SUCCESS-->346((346));style 700 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;701((701))-->346((346));style 701 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;700((700))--LMS_SUBMIT_APPLICATION_FAILED-->347((347));style 700 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;701((701))-->347((347));style 701 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;347((347))-->346((346));style 347 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;700((700))--LOAN_APPLICATION_REJECTED-->351((351));style 700 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;701((701))-->351((351));style 701 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;351((351))-->347((347));style 351 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;351((351))-->346((346));style 351 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;346((346))-->330((330));style 346 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;346((346))--LMS_CALLBACK_REJECTED-->333((333));style 346 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;346((346))--LMS_CALLBACK_PENDING-->334((334));style 346 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;346((346))--LMS_CALLBACK_FAILED-->345((345));style 346 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;330((330))--LEAD_SUCCESSFULLY_CLOSED-->156((156));style 330 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;333((333))--NOTIFICATION_SUCCESS-->167((167));style 333 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;333((333))--NOTIFICATION_ERROR-->168((168));style 333 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;167((167))--LEAD_FAILURE-->504((504));style 167 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;168((168))-->504((504));style 168 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;334((334))-->330((330));style 334 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;334((334))-->333((333));style 334 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;334((334))-->345((345));style 334 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;334((334))-->334((334));style 334 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;345((345))-->330((330));style 345 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;345((345))-->333((333));style 345 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;345((345))-->334((334));style 345 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;345((345))-->345((345));style 345 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;112((112))-->114((114));style 112 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;700((700))-->350((350));style 700 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;346((346))-->504((504));style 346 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;346((346))--LMS_CALLBACK_PENDING_BANK_PAN-->359((359));style 346 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;112((112))-->358((358));style 112 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->350((350));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->357((357));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->555((555));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;558((558))-->428((428));style 558 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;558((558))-->558((558));style 558 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;558((558))-->179((179));style 558 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;366((366))--UPDATE_LOAN_OFFER-->377((377));style 366 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;377((377))-->355((355));style 377 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;428((428))-->428((428));style 428 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->428((428));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;428((428))-->179((179));style 428 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;114((114))-->179((179));style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;style 114 fill:#f00,stroke:#333,stroke-width:4px;`",
                  ^
}
```

That's why you have a syntax error. Remove it in the data to fix the problem.

You must've copy-pasted the data INCLUDING the backticks from other code and forgot to remove them.